# react-native-neomorph-shadows : Error in iphone 12

Tags: css, react-native, user-interface

Hi I am facing issue with `react-native-neomorph-shadows` library. App crashes immediately after build being successful. I am not sure what is the issue.
macOS version: 11.2.3

**Edit-1**

Package.json dependency:

```
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-neomorph-shadows": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0"
```

Error:
`error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/ShadowFlex from /Users/manikanttiwari/Desktop/test/app/node_modules/react-native-neomorph-shadows/index.js`

Comment: Do you have any sort of logs?

Comment: please add package.json dependencies.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, I have updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to solve this problem. Please do `npm i https://github.com/react-native-art/art.git` instead of `react-native link @react-native-community/art`. This will solve the problem.